# Well vs Well up | Fill vs Fill up

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

As I find out some verbs in Oxford, **well (up)** and **fill (up)**, has the particle given in round brackets, so...

> ...Is there a difference in meaning between the verb **well** and
>   **well up**; **fill** and **fill up**?

---

Meanings of well (up) and fill (up) in Oxford:

- [**well (up)**](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/well_5#well_inflg_4) (of a liquid) to rise to the surface of something and
  start to flow => *Tears were welling up in her eyes.*

  **well (up)** (literary) (of an emotion) to become stronger => *Hate welled
  up inside him as he thought of the two of them together.*
- [**fill somebody/yourself (up) (with something)**](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/fill_1?q=fill) (informal) to make
  somebody/yourself feel unable to eat any more => *The kids filled
  themselves with snacks.*

  **fill something (up)** to use up a particular period of time doing
  something => *How do you fill your day now that you've retired?*

Comment: Are you wondering specifically about these verbs, or are you wondering about what the parenthesis symbols, (), mean in this dictionary?

Comment: @ReinstateMonica Well I want to know both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Fill X up* when X is something that contains liquid often has the literal meaning and not the phrasal meaning.

> My eyes filled up with tears

This means the eyes (capable of containing some quantity of tears) are now full of tears (and presumably dripping down the face).

This meaning of *fill up*  can be interchanged with *well up*, even though they don't mean the same thing.

Comment: In sentence 'My eyes filled up with tears', do you think 'Fill up' and 'Fill without up' have the **same meaning** and we can use them interchangeably?

Comment: Phrasal *up* can mean "completely", and *fill up* means *fill completely*.  So *fill up with tears* is a more intense way of saying *fill with tears*.